# Is it normal ops to dispatch an airplane after a stick shaker was on throughout the previous flight (Lion Air 610)?

Tags: boeing-737, accident-investigation

I've been studying Figures 5 and 7 of the Lion Air interim report and cannot understand why the airplane was dispatched on the "Loss-of-control" flight when the Left stick-shaker was on throughout the entire previous flight (Figure 7). Can this occur in normal operations everywhere?
I have no experience with ground operations (just 35 years with design of flight control equipment), so I'm asking the airline folks here. (I understand that often multiple causes lead to a crash, so I'm looking for understanding, not blame.)

[image: Data Recorder chart from Lion Air flight prior to 610]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it discusses an accident that is still under investigation.

Comment: Why is the AoA constant during climb and descent?

Comment: @Pheric in any non-accelerated flight situation (basically everything except initiating and ending a climb or descent, and turning) the AoA is only a function of airspeed, mass, flap deflection and air density. Since these factors remain roughly constant for most of climb and descent, so does the AoA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if the shaker was running abnormally like that, the crew would have done a QRH procedure, if any, for that condition, and reported the snag at the next stop, and something would have been done by maintenance to release the plane.  Like a part was changed, or the problem went away and couldn't be duplicated after a test was done on the ground, whatever was required to get a maintenance release.  It would have to have been released as serviceable, one way or another.

Comment: Very clear answer! You just taught me about QRH and I spotted a description at [What exactly is a QRH](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2858/what-exactly-is-a-qrh) Thanks.