# How is fuel dumping safe?

Tags: safety, fuel-dumping

The answers to this [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8136/3170) make it clear how modern airliners dump fuel in the case of an emergency. As far as I understand, fuel dumping might be done to lower an aircraft's weight to the maximum landing weight, particularly soon after takeoff.

As far as I understand, jet fuel is typically not safe. When I, as a complete outsider, hear of fuel dumping, I imagine a whole bunch of dangerous corrosive fuel being dropped on whatever happens to be below, and it sounds like a frankly awful idea.

What makes fuel dumping safe, or if it is dangerous what makes it worth it?

Comment: Jet fuel isn't corrosive and the dumped fuel evaporates before it reaches the ground anyway.

Comment: Lol at "dangerous corrosive" fuel. It's kerosene, sprayed over a very big area.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: That depends on many conditions like rain, temperature and altitude of dumping. I can remember a situation where some test airbus dumped fuel over our living area and you could smell it.

Comment: Here's some aircraft maintenance trivia: we called the valve that controls the dump a *Jesus Valve*. I'm not sure what the pilots call it, but its a bad day if they have to use it.

Comment: At that height even if you blow a nuke nothing will be felt on the ground except EMP.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Fuel dumping is almost always an emergency maneuver, and it is never good for the environment.  So the alleged danger from the dumping must be balanced with the imminent danger to the 200–400 passengers involved.  It is never an easy decision but that's why the Captain gets paid the big bucks...

Dumping fuel sounds dangerous but it is not.  It is not going to explode.  Jet-A can be compared to kerosene and I don't have that statistic so let's compare it to Diesel Fuel which is not dissimilar to Jet-A.  Diesel Fuel at 400°F(204°C) is as volatile as gasoline is at 70°F(21°C).  Obviously that is a big difference.  Jet-A also evaporates into the air, so little if any hits the ground.

The biggest danger I see is to the atmosphere.

Comment: misted fuel can still ignite but if you are going at mach 0.7 it won't catch up to you

Comment: Since when do airline pilots get paid the big bucks? ...or is that a joke? :)

Comment: @egid - `The starting salary for a captain with a medium-sized airline may range from £57,000 to £78,000, while those with the major operators could earn from £97,000 to more than £140,000. A pilot's salary is often incremental, rising with each year of service with the company.` Sure, it's not millions, but that is pretty big amount of money.

Comment: @egid: Yes, meant to be a joke.

Comment: @Davor those numbers seem pretty high for US carriers. Maybe it's different overseas.

Comment: @Davor See [Do commercial airline pilots make around \$19,000 - \$25,000 per year?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4845/do-commercial-airline-pilots-make-around-19-000-25-000-per-year)

Comment: @DJClayworth - so? A pilot with zero experience flying bananas from Brazil makes 20k. Terrible. Or do you expect every newbie to make as much money as renowned experts in the field?

Comment: @egid - I worked for Delta Airlines in aircraft maintenance in the 1990s. I saw a wide body pilot's paystub (wide body is significant because more senior pilots fly it). The pay stub was left in the cockpit during an overhaul. I *don't* recall how much the captain made. But I made about 50K or 60K a year, and I recall the captain put that much in his 401K that year. I don't think anyone makes that kind of money anymore (except the executives, whose pay probably went up while others were taking pay cuts).

Comment: @DJClayworth: It seems to be situation specific to the US where many private pilots want the job. In parts of the world without that big pool of private pilots the wages are better.

Comment: I beg to differ about the decision to dump fuel being difficult. *Nope*. If you face a situation where you must land sooner than expected and you're over max landing weight, you dump fuel if your plane has that ability. As simple as that. There's no telenovela style gazing in the cockpit, no extra perspiration, no echoing voices pondering all the mistakes you made in life. Just find an apropriate area nearby, dump whatever you don't need and land. It damn sure is not on the list of things that justify higher than average wages of airline pilots.

Answer (score 24):

It's not really safe in an environmental sense, but it's not that bad.  Jet fuel is essentially kerosene, which is harmful, but as far as engine/industrial fluids go, it's pretty benign.  Additionally, when an airplane dumps it, it's diluted so much by the time it makes it anywhere that it's not a significant concern anymore.

On the flip side, if an airplane didn't dump fuel and landed overweight, the potential side effects could be disastrous and could result in many injuries and damages.

Basically, it's choosing between two bad options, landing overweight or dumping fuel, and dumping fuel is the least bad of the two of them.

In any case, it's quite a rare occurrence.  You are exposed to far more toxins just walking down the street of a city than from airplanes dumping fuel.

Comment: Great answer but I'd like to add that the cost of dumped fuel is another consideration, which you have to sacrifice for safety.

Answer (score 15):

Up-voting @skipmiller, I offer this addendum

> if it is dangerous what makes it worth it?

### Emergency Landing After Takeoff

Large aircraft typically cannot land as heavily as they can take off. It's a structural issue. So fuel dumping would be done if an emergency did not allow the time to burn down to allowable landing weight.

### Maintain Flight with Engine/Power Loss

If available power did not allow sustained flight one might dump fuel. Worse if you were over mountains and needed to stay high.

### Ditching

There was a case of a C-130 - a high wing plane - ditching in the Atlantic. It floated for a couple days with empty gas tanks and had to be shelled to force it to sink.

### Fuel Leak

If a wing tank fuel leak was causing aircraft balance problems one might dump from the opposite wing to keep the aircraft controllable.

### Life Imitating Fiction

15 minutes after takeoff we lost all thrust on 3 engines. Our gross weight forced us into a controlled descent. Dumping most of our fuel might very well have kept us airborne on 1 engine, if not I think empty tanks would have limited possible fuel fire in the controlled crash. I was about to dump 45,000 lbs of JP-4 all over west Texas when we solved our engine problem.

Comment: Very cool points, but I don't understand the ditching example. Was fuel dumped to make the plane lighter so it would float better?

Comment: Navigation error caused them to run out of fuel.

Comment: So what does it have to do with fuel dumping? Have there been any cases where a plane has dumped fuel specifically to float better after ditching?

Comment: It's a consideration. And I just illustrated the point where empty tanks helped keep the aircraft afloat. But I may concede a point - I don't think Sullenburger dumped fuel when he went into the Hudson. I don't think his airplane had a dump system.

Comment: Just to point out that while an empty tank will certainly float better than a tank full of Jet-A, the full tank will also float because Jet-A is around 6.7 lbs/gal and sea water is greater than 8 lbs/gal.

Comment: @Terry only if the Jet-A + the steel/aluminum container and whatever is attached to it is lighter than water, it's not enough that the Jet-A is :)

Comment: ` I was about to dump 45,000 lbs` Well, better safe than sorry, wouldn't it be better to dump it anyway in case they fail again ?

Answer (score 0):

Fuel dumping is done by many types of Aircraft(fighter etc.) it is not limited to the role(cargo, passenger etc.). Although the purpose may be same.(Sometimes its done to reduce the load, to avoid any accident).

In a fighter plane fuel is dumped to reduce the weight and increase the distance to cover(the weapons it carries already has tons of weight on the plane). This could be the same in passenger but situations may vary.

Fuel dumping is really a serious threat to the environment or the biological impact  especially if it's dumped in the water(causes damage to maritime species and irreversible damage to the coral reefs if present).

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and say dumping fuel from a fighter plane won't increase its range.

Comment: Not range but payload/speed