# Do airplanes dump fuel before landing?

Tags: landing, fuel

Presumably planes aren't completely empty of fuel when the land, so they don't start refueling from zero, is that right? Is it true that they must dump excess fuel before they land? How much? Presumably not all, in case there's a problem with the landing and they need to abort?

Comment: @ymb1 not a duplicate, doesn't answer the question if they're empty on landing (they're not by the way)

Comment: Their can be reasons for a plane to offload fuel *after* landing (or before the next takeoff) but that would be more likely to apply to a small plane, where the weight of "full tanks of fuel" plus "the maximum number of passengers" exceeds the maximum takeoff weightof the plane. Of course you would try to plan ahead so this waste of money was avoidable. Except in very weird circumstances (e.g. the shortest commercial passenger flight lasts just 47 seconds, between two Scottish islands!) this would be irrelevant for a commercial airline

Comment: Don't you have any idea how expensive fuel is?

Comment: @kevin Likely the person asking the question does not know how expensive fuel is, and perhaps it's why they are asking the question. This site exists for people to ask questions. If people already knew everything the site would have no purpose. I don't know how expensive aviation fuel is either - perhaps it would be an interesting question to ask.

Comment: @DanieleProcida I meant it in an inoffensive, friendly tone (=

Comment: Yes, whenever I have excess fuel left at the end of a flight I fly over the parking area and see if any those jerkoffs flying Extra 300s or Pitts Specials are around and then I dump it on them.

Answer (score 32):

> Is it true that they must dump excess fuel before they land?

Nope. You don't siphon your car just before your destination. Fuel is money.

Except in emergency in big planes, fuel then is a potentially lethal burden (weight).

> ... in case there's a problem with the landing and they need to abort?

Contingency fuel just for aborted landings, weather deviations, etc., is added during the fuel loading for such things. You get to keep it at the destination.

---

Further reading:

- [When are aircraft required to dump fuel for emergency landings?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2854/14897)
- [Can a wide body airliner land safely with a full fuel tank?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33252/14897)
- [Fuel planning—fuel calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_planning#Fuel_calculation)

Comment: "fuel then is a potentially lethal burden (weight)", and also highly flammable.

Comment: @isanae planes are designed to be able to land fully fueled but it may damage the gear/blow a tire/overheat the brakes. Landing overweight also means that the plane needs to be checked over before it can fly again.

Comment: @ratchetfreak But you have more factors, e.g. [Quantas 32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qantas_Flight_32) landed overweight in Singapore with about 100 m left of the runway, which was a pretty nigh and could have easily led to a disaster. So while the plane is designed to do the task, other things have to be considered.

Comment: @yo': _"which was a pretty nigh"_ ?

Comment: Good answer. Perhaps an edit to include details of military aviation is required? I would imagine they are less concerned with fuel costs.

Comment: This quote from wikipedia is also of interest:  "Many movies and TV news stories mistakenly assume that all aircraft can dump fuel, when in fact most cannot."

Comment: @David Planes where the maximum takeoff weight is more than 1.05 times the maximum landing weight are required to have fuel dump capability. See [this answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/2855/755). However, you're correct that this condition doesn't apply to most planes and most planes don't have the capability. It's mostly just aircraft designed for long-haul operations where the maximum takeoff weight is much higher than the maximum landing weight.

Comment: In addition to the economic costs of wasting fuel, dumping fuel is also very bad for the environment.  Even in an emergency there will be efforts to dump the fuel over the ocean or in a less environmentally damaging area if the emergency not so severe as to require immediate action.  Dumping fuel is an action of last resort and is really only ever done if it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - never heard "the end is nigh"?

Comment: @Davor: Of course, but that's not what yo' said. I've never seen "nigh" used as a noun, nor can I locate a definition for such usage in any dictionary. Please do provide reference material if you disagree.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - He didn't use it as a noun. "There was only 100 meters left, which was pretty nigh (near)." What makes you think this is a noun?

Comment: @reirab The regulation you're referring to that requires fuel-dumping capability (14 CFR 25.1001), was amended in 1968 and since then has been performance, not weight-based.  Additionally, there are various exceptions to the old 1.05 times rule like GA aircraft and the 737-200.

Answer (score 19):

I assume we're speaking of commercial air services such as airliners.

## Generally, landing with less fuel is better than with more

It's better for an aircraft to land with less rather than more fuel. Fuel can make up a very large proportion of its total weight and it's inefficient and uneconomic to fly around unneeded fuel.

## "Enough" fuel includes a safety margin

An aircraft will be despatched with more fuel than is required simply to get it to its destination: it needs to have enough to deal safely with unexpected headwinds, a long holding pattern before landing, a diversion due to an airport closure and so on.

## A heavily-fuelled aircraft can be "overweight" for landing

Above a certain weight, an aircraft exceeds its correct limits for landing. This can make landing difficult and at worst could damage the airframe through over-stress.

If a landing is required before the aircraft has consumed enough fuel for a within-specifications landing (by some sort of emergency or an unexpected airport closure):

- the pilot can burn off fuel in a holding pattern
- fuel can be dumped if the model has that capability
- the aircraft will land overweight if it lacks the capability or needs to land before fuel can be dumped

## Aircraft may routinely land with extra fuel

For operational reasons an aircraft may land with more fuel on board than was needed for a particular flight - for example, it may be less expensive to carry the extra fuel than refuel at a particular stop.

## In short

The general answer however:

- Aircraft will be fuelled to land with the minimum possible unnecessary fuel.
- If an aircraft has to burn off or jettison fuel before landing, that's not a routine operation, and it indicates that something has gone wrong.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that excess fuel is routinely dumped by commercial airlines in non-emergency situations. I am fairly certain that is untrue.

Comment: It's most definitely not the case! What makes you think I'm suggesting that? If it's ambiguous it needs to be changed.

Comment: Read your fourth paragraph carefully. It suggests that if a plane is above weight, it will only land at that weight if there's a problem. But otherwise, if it needs to land at above weight, it will dump fuel if it has that capability. That is not true.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm not sure what you think is not true. An aircraft that lands overweight does so only because of a problem. If there is a problem that requires a landing while overweight, fuel will be jettisoned if possible. However I will rewrite to clarify.

Comment: Your answer now explicitly states that an airliner that is overweight to land due to an airport closure would dump fuel in a non-urgent situation. (Well, technically it says fuel "can" be dumped, but of course it wouldn't be.) You've combined the emergency procedures with the routine ones in that list.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You can't land at the destination airport because the runway has been closed due to bad weather. The two airports you *can* reach with your fuel will close their own runways (also for bad weather) in less time than it will take you to burn off the fuel you're carrying. So, you will dump it if you have the capability.

Comment: Right, but not because of the airport closure. Because of all the other factors you mentioned. You would never dump fuel because of an airport closure. You would not a case where not dumping fuel would create some real problem.

Comment: @DanieleProcida, if your choice of airport is limited by available fuel, you are _way below_ MLW.

Comment: @DanieleProcida, if the destination airport is closed, you are going to the alternate and that is close to the destination, so you have/will burn all the fuel planned to go to destination, plus possibly some more depending on when you decided to divert. You don't have anything to dump either way.

Comment: @JanHudec *All kinds of wholly unexpected things can happen* - and have done. Airspace can be shut down across a nation. A war can break out. Freak weather conditions can erupt very fast. The circumstances might be unusual or even extremely rare, but that's not the same as saying that there are no conceivable conditions under which they might arise.

Comment: @DanieleProcida That's a silly argument. That's like saying it's reasonable to say you might need to cut of your arm because you're late for lunch (without qualification) because it's theoretically possible to imagine an incredibly rare chain of events that starts with you being late for lunch and ends with you needing to cut off your arm. Is is absolutely not procedure to dump fuel because of an airport closure, and your answer says it is.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "Silly" or not, it's something that has happened. When airspace and airports closed across the USA on 11th September 2011, many flights were forced to dump fuel in order to land as quickly as possible. That's the nature of emergencies in aviation: they're rare, and they can involve extraordinary chains of events.

Comment: @DanieleProcida I said the argument was silly and explained why. I didn't say it hasn't happened, just that it cannot form the basis for the argument you made. People have died from papercuts, but if you put death on a list of things that result from papercuts, you're just making a silly argument.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: If someone asked the question "Do people die from paper cuts", it would be totally reasonable to answer "Generally no, but under certain rare circumstances it has happened" - that's hardly a silly response :)

Comment: Right, and that's what's missing from your answer.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: My answer?!

Answer (score 8):

Here's the TLDR answer.

> Presumably planes aren't completely empty of fuel when the land, so they don't start refueling from zero, is that right?

**Planes aren't completely empty when they land:** you can tell this because they land with the engines on. And, as you say, they need sufficient extra fuel in case they have to abort a landing, or the airport is congested and they need to circle, or the headwinds were stronger than expected or a myriad of other things.

> Is it true that they must dump excess fuel before they land?

**Planes only dump fuel in emergencies,** and not all planes can dump fuel. Fuel is one of the airlines' biggest costs so they don't routinely throw it away. Fuel may have to be dumped because the maximum allowed take-off weight is usually much higher than the maximum allowed landing weight: if you've flown, you can tell that landing is harder on the plane than taking off. Fuel can be around half the weight of the plane at take-off. In case of an emergency early in the flight, one has to weigh up the pros and cons of staying in the air longer to dump fuel and land within or closer to the allowed weight, versus landing overweight straight away.

Answer (score 4):

Typically the aircraft is fueled with enough for the flight plus extra for one or two diversions beyond the destination.  Only in emergencies or when it's necessary will they land with over-excess fuel.

Having less fuel in the tanks is less fuel to burn if there is risk of breakup on landing or when landing gears can't be lowered into position.  Landing on the planes belly could puncture the tanks so this helps that.

Not all jets have fuel jettison capability, not on the typical Boeing 737 or Airbus A320 series, they can only reduce fuel by burn, so they'll fly around for hours in a holding pattern near the airport until safe to land.

Fuel dumping is built into the large wide body jets like a Boeing 777 or 747 and the big Airbus models.  This is due to their long ranges and large amount of fuel required for the journey, these planes are designed with a maximum take-off that is greater than their maximum safe landing weight.

Fully fueled, once airborne they cannot land while overweight or risk over-stressing the structure and possibly overheating the brakes.

There have been a few instances of Pilots being forced to land anyway, such as possible fire.  In every case a full inspection will be mandatory before the plane can return to service.  This depends on the damages, sometimes all is needed is another set of tires and brakes, or if the landing causes cracks in the structure it could be too expensive for repairs so is scrapped.

Answer (score 1):

There have been many explanations given but ultimately the answer to your question is "**No, aircraft do not dump fuel prior to landing unless it is absolutely necessary.**"

During an emergency fuel may be dumped to reduce landing weight and reduce the  likelihood of fire. These facts have been established by many others above.

What hasn't been covered is **Speed**. An aircraft carrying many thousands of kilograms of fuel requires higher speeds to keep flying. With higher speed you need more runway space to bring the aircraft to a stop. Dumping fuel reduces weight and therefore speed.

So, fuel is dumped to reduce weight, speed, braking distance and to reduce the chance of fire. Aircraft can land overweight but it is far from ideal and requires extra distance on the ground. Normally if a flight is closer to its destination fuel dumping might not be required, however closer to departure point dumping is more likely in an extreme emergency. Factors such as runway length and nature of emergency will influence the decision made by the Pilot In Command.

An alternative to dumping fuel is dumping passengers, and keep the fuel, but that requires a lot of extra paperwork and probably affects the pilots career :)

Comment: Landing overweight also requires that the airplane be taken out of service and inspected, which is even more expensive than throwing away fuel. While cost should never be a factor in making safety decisions, it *can* be factored in if all other things are being equal. For example, if the plane needs to go back for some non-critical issue (e.g. airconditioning broken), then the pilot will probably choose to dump (or burn) fuel rather than perform an overweight landing. If, OTOH, the airplane is on fire, he will land overweight, and risk the brakes overheating and the airframe overstressing.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thinking about it from that perspective... what are the resultant costs of cleaning up after a fuel dump? It feels like if you dump several tons of volatile petroleum into the air, it's got to go somewhere. While in practice this is probably an external cost (ie, one borne by a third party) and the airline ignores it, I wonder if it's considered anywhere..

Comment: @Andrew read [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8147/how-is-fuel-dumping-safe) for info on what happens to dumped fuel.

Comment: @Andrew: You dump several tons of petroleum into 5.5 quadrillion tons of air. Noone's gonna notice.

Comment: This wiki entry might be useful. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_gravity_of_an_aircraft#Fuel_dumping_and_overweight_operations

Answer (score 0):

A commercial airliner only takes the fuel required for the flight plan, this is calculated and provided to the flight crew prior to departure. They then decide the right amount taking into account weather, potential delays etc... This is normally just enough for the leg to be flown i.e. fuel from departure to destination plus reserves and alternate fuel.

Commercial aircraft are required to land at destination with final reserve fuel, which dependant on the national authority is the minimum fuel required to fly for 30 (or 45) minutes at 1,500 feet above the alternate aerodrome. You can burn your alternate fuel if you're confident in landing at destination. If it looks like you're going to land with less than final reserve you are required to declare an emergency.

So to answer the question, no dumping fuel is not routine, you will always land with some, the amount depends on the type of aircraft type.